# Flutter column children displays an unwanted order

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a login page using `SingleChildScrollView` and `column` widgets to display my collection but for some reason, the order is totally absurd and changing the mainAxisAlignment isnt helping.

[image: image shows the output]

This is my code:

```
Container(
            height: lotusGet.height,
            padding: LOTUS_COLLECTION_PADDING,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: LotusRoundButton(
                      press: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.chevron_left,
                        color: lotusGet.accentColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const LotusLogo(
                  text: 'log in',
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 0.01 * height,
                ),
                _ErrorText(
                  height: height,
                  lotusGet: lotusGet,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 0.03 * height,
                ),
                _LoginForm(
                  loginformKey: loginformKey,
                  height: height,
                  lotusGet: lotusGet,
                  emailController: emailController,
                  showPassword: showPassword,
                  passwordController: passwordController,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

As can be seen from the code and common sense, the logo should be above the form but the opposite occurs, anyone know why?

Comment: Are you using  `reversed: true`?

Comment: that property is not available for columns,only listviews which i am not using in this case

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your issue in isolation, with standard Widgets, without your custom code?

Comment: im not sure i follow but this occurs on sign up page as well ... p.s debug console shows no errors

Comment: @ClioTech, I believe Joao means to take out your custom "_LoginForm()" and "_LotusLogo()" widgets and see whether Flutter renders all of the standard widgets in the expected order.  If it does, then there'll be something about your custom widget methods that is confusing the layout.

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your code, the dart file that contains this snippet, something is reversing the order of items.